# Error writing data using spark using Cassandra SparkBulkAnalytics- IllegalAccessException: access to public member failed jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner.cle

Tags: cassandra

**
Issue Details:**  When trying to write data from spark into Cassandra using Spark Bulk Analytics Cassandra side car component, we are getting the below  IllegalAccessException: access to public member failed Error

**Reference: **https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16222, CEP-28: Reading and Writing Cassandra Data with Spark Bulk Analytics, https://github.com/frankgh/cassandra-sidecar/

**Code we are usign to write from spark:**

df.write.format("org.apache.cassandra.spark.sparksql.CassandraDataSink").option("sidecar_instances", "10.x.x.x”).option("bulk_writer_cl", "LOCAL_QUORUM").option("LOCAL_DC", "dcx”).option("table", “xxtable”).option("keyspace", “xxkeyspace”).mode("append").save()

We updated the jdk from 8 to 11 while building the jars.

**Error Message:** ERROR FileUtils: FATAL: Cassandra is unable to access required classes. This usually means it has been run without the aid of the standard startup scripts or the scripts have been edited. If this was intentional, and you are attempting to use Java 11+ you may need to add the --add-exports and --add-opens jvm options from either jvm11-server.options or jvm11-client.options
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to public member failed: jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner.clean[Ljava.lang.Object;@3d9de44d/invokeVirtual, from org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils (unnamed module @dc31a1)

at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.(FileUtils.java:107)

... 56 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to public member failed: jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner.clean[Ljava.lang.Object;@40b014a2/invokeVirtual, from org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils (unnamed module @6a96af98)

at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:942)